# MSSQL 2008 - Select only one way or the route

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with routes like this:

Source - Destination
Bogota - Monteria
Monteria - Bogota
Cali - Bogota
Bogota - Medellin

I want to only select one way of the route to display it on a map. 
So as a result i want only

Bogota - Monteria
Cali - Bogota
Bogota - Medellin

Can any one point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement so that the route ends are allocated consistent columns per alphabetical order.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE
                  WHEN Source > Destination THEN Destination
                  ELSE Source
                END,
                CASE
                  WHEN Source > Destination THEN Source
                  ELSE Destination
                END
FROM   Routes
```